# delete substring from env variable doesn't work in shell

Tags: shell, variables, substring

I was trying to delete a path from my PATH variable using the shell string manipulation approach: ${string%$substring}. It works for common variable but it doesn't work when I want to delete a path in PATH variable.

```
xiangxue➜~» echo $PATH [10:34:16]   
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/xiangxue/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

Suppose I would like to delete :/usr/games entry from PATH, I did this:

```
xiangxue➜~» echo ${PATH%:/usr/games} [10:40:12]
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/xiangxue/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

The PATH doesn't delete :/usr/games entry, and it  looks exactly same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `${parameter%pattern}` string manipulation removes from the end of the string (see the Bash Guide on [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) or the Bash [Reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) or the [POSIX Spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)) but `:/usr/games` isn't at the end of your string so it doesn't match.

The expansion you want for this is the `${parameter/pat/string}` expansion:

```
echo "${PATH/:\/usr\/games}"
```

Alternatively you want to split `$PATH` on `:` and loop to filter out your desired entry.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed 's/:\/usr\/games:/:/g;s/:\/usr\/games//g;s/\/usr\/games://g')

user@host:/tmp$ PATH=/usr/games:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/games:/bin:/usr/games
user@host:/tmp$ echo $PATH
/usr/games:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/games:/bin:/usr/games
user@host:/tmp$ PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed 's/:\/user\/games:/:/g;s/:\/usr\/games//g;s/\/usr\/games://g')
user@host:/tmp$ echo $PATH
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```